# Trying to reset zoom w/Google map API when viewed on mobile device

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, zooming

Firstly I am a hobbyist, and am trying to reset the zoom level of a google map using jquery and google's API when viewed on a mobile device. I'm not able to get this to work with the following code. The last 6 lines I found on this site, but I'm not sure of the placement. I understood it to be at the end of the script.  I've tried different placements but haven't been successful.

```
var locations = [
  ['Bowser, BC', 49.434, -124.683, 1],
  ['Calgary, AB', 51.103, -114.186, 2]
  
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 6,
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(50.686,-119.819),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}

var screenWidth = window.screen.width * window.devicePixelRatio;
var screenHeight = window.screen.height * window.devicePixelRatio;
if (screenWidth < 600 && typeof map !== "undefined")
{
    map.setZoom(12);
}
```

The map does not resize on mobile device...but I know its possible since I was able to get this to work using a directions map, but I don't want that map type. Truly appreciate any help...I think I'm close just not close enough!

## Update:

I tried debugging this but am having difficulty understanding outputs if any using chrome.  Instead I googled jquery techniques for detecting mobile screens.  I ended up doing this, changed the last six lines above to:

```
      var windowWidth=window.screen.width;
         if (windowWidth < 600 )
         {
             map.setZoom(4);
           }
```

Then added this to CSS:

```
    @media all and (min-width: 720px) {
          #map {width:auto;}
        }
```

I'm sure this will have 'true' developers losing sleep at night, but it is working on my mobile phone (S9).